# Pass variable as parameter in jquery .load

Tags: jquery, variables, load

I have an html DL list.
Whenever I click on a DD, I would like to get its class name and pass it as a parameter to the Jquery .load function.

This is my code:

How do I change the .kilye class in order for it to get the class from the elementClass variable?

```
$('dd').click(function(){
$('#img').show();
var elementClass = $(this).attr("class");
$(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
$('.bio').load('/people/index.html .kilye', function(){
   $('#img').hide();
   $('.bio').slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
```

Comment: You can pass it as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple string concatenation:

```
 $('.bio').load('/people/index.html .'+ elementClass, function(){})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   $('dd').click(function(){
    $('#img').show();
    var elementClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    var url = '/people/index.html .'+elementClass;
    $('.bio').load(url, function(){
       $('#img').hide();
       $('.bio').slideToggle('slow');
       });
    });
```